# Can I ask Lightroom to delete copied photos from the SD card?

Tags: lightroom, sdcard, backup

I have a 32GB SD card, and I find that I run out of space on the card sooner than I'd like. Can I get Lightroom to delete the photos from the SD card after they have been copied to the Mac? Not just moved to the Trash, but deleted, to recover space. I don't find such an option.

Yes, this means that if my Mac corrupts its hard disc, I'm more likely to lose my photos, but I don't see any other option, short of buying a 64GB SD card or carrying multiple cards with me. (I do own multiple cards, but they are all slower than my primary card.)

So:

- Can LR reclaim space on the SD card when I copy photos out of it?
- How would you suggest I deal with this situation?

EDIT: Sorry, I had left out an important piece of information -- I convert to DNG while importing, and LR has a "Copy as DNG" option, but no "Move as DNG" option. I could do a "Move" followed by a conversion to DNG, but I find the Copy as DNG easier.

Footnote: My Mac did corrupt its hard disc once, losing everything on it (full-disk encryption meant that I couldn't connect it to another Mac and copy the data out). But my SD card got corrupted once, as well, so I don't know whether my photos would be safer on the SD card or on the Mac. It's probably the same thing either way.

Footnote 2: In an ideal world, the photos would just be marked as copied (or moved to the /.Trashes directory on the SD card), and the camera would automatically delete them to reclaim space as needed. This is like the Windows recycle bin. Unfortunately, I see that only on Windows, not on the Mac, to say nothing of my camera.

Comment: Have you tried using the "Move" rather than "Copy" option in the Lightroom Import tool? When you move, the images SHOULD be deleted from the memory card.

Comment: Regarding hard disc corruption...you should have an automated backup running, preferably backing up your critical data to an external hard drive or NAS device. I've lost five hard dives (four WD and one Seagate...will NEVER buy another WD again) in the last two years, so I purchased a NetGear ReadyNAS NVX, stuffed four 2Tb (8Tb total) Hitachi/Toshiba drives (DAMN GOOD DRIVES...180mb/s sustained transfer, high reliability) in it with X-RAID (dynamic RAID), and let my automated backups do their thing. I never worry about failed hard drives anymore.

Comment: I do put of my critical stuff in Dropbox. Unfortunately, RAW files are too big to sync to the cloud, for me. I periodically backup my Macbook to an external drive and to multiple desktops, once in several months. So I have a general backup strategy I am happy with, and that strikes a good balance between convenience and safety of data. I don't think leaving a NAS device plugged in and running 24/7 is good for the drive or the data in it, given the power fluctuations in India.

Comment: I convert to DNG, and unfortunately there's no "Move as DNG" option -- there's "Copy as DNG", "Copy" and "Move", of which Copy as DNG is the least troublesome for me to use.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the DNG stuff.

Comment: Im pretty sure move is only when you do it on your harddrive. You can only pick copy from the flash cards.

Comment: When I was on vacation, I dumped the SD card to a MacBook each day.  I made three copies before erasing the card: the built-in drive, and two different partions on a travel drive.  Just drag - don't use Lightroom or anything.  Process the local files If you want to go through them.

Comment: @jrista I use a RAID6 with ZFS.  I worry about silent corruption of old files.  Common file systems won't notice that, nor correct a bad read that's not a hardware reported read error.

Comment: @jdlugosz: The Ready-NAS with X-RAID does regular scrubbing, which goes through all the data on the entire array and checks it out, reorganizes and optimizes it. So, there can't be silent corruption...the system is always checking itself, identifying bad blocks, and moving data. If a block on one drive is bad, it can always be rebuilt with parity.

Comment: @jrista X-RAID is just automated and expanable but essentially RAID5, with a file system on top.  Scrub tests the file system for consistency, but it does not cause every sector of file content to be hashed and checked upon reading, so it doesn't know if a sector was written wrong or silently corrupted, or which redundant copy is correct.  Having full integrity checking in the file system is another feature over just having redundancy.

Comment: @jdlugosz: Sorry, that is not the case. With the ReadyNAS, scrubbing is basically doing a resync. That touches every block on the device and verifies the data. It takes about a day and a half to complete, and the device is running heavily the entire time. The benefit of doing this on X-RAID is, unlike most resyncs, if the device loses power or is otherwise shut off in the middle of the scrubbing process, it will properly recover when it boots again. I've had some brownouts and power outages where the power flickers on and off a number of times, or dropping, then returning for a few minutes...

Comment: ...then dropping again. In such situations, the device will launch right into a verification mode and start a resync, only to have power fail again right in the middle of that. I've never once lost any data on my ReadyNAS, and I've had it for years. It's a nearly impervious device, and it DOES regularly (weekly, on the schedule I've set) scrub and resync the array to ensure that the chance of bad blocks causing problems is extremely low.

Comment: @jrista I see; the mentions of xraid I've seen don't go into that.  How does it know if some block (not holding file system metadata) is readable but wrong?

Comment: @jdlugosz: It's a full parity RAID, so it has full error correction information distributed across all the drives. In my case, I have four drives in my array. I don't know the underlying details, as in specifically how it verifies each block, but I know it can and does make sure the data is correct everywhere on the whole array when it is doing it's scrubbing/resync process. I've actually done a live (online) drive replacement...I took out one of my smaller drives, and added a larger one. The device kept operating, and automatically rebuilt the data on the removed drive onto the newly added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the bearer of bad news: Despite what other have suggested, the answer to your question is NO. Lightroom (3,4 and 5) does not support Moving images from SD card.

[See P39 of the Lightroom 5 manual:](http://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/lightroom_reference.pdf)

> In the top center of the import window, specify how you want to add the photos to the catalog:
>
> - **Copy as DNG** Copies camera raw files to the folder you choose and converts them to the Digital Negative (DNG) format.
> - **Copy** Copies the photo files to the folder you choose, including any sidecar files.
> - **Move** Moves the photo files to the folder you choose, including any sidecar files. Files are removed from their current location.
> - **Add** Keeps the photo files in their current location.
>
> **Note: The Move and Add options are not available when importing
> from a camera card.**

Having explored a bit on the Mac side, I think I have a way for you to get what you want. It involves the Mac's Image Capture and AutoImporter tools.

The workflow basically runs like this: Use Image Capture app to specify that AutoImporter is to open when the SD card is inserted. You can then configure AutoImporter to move the pictures to a specified folder, and remove the originals from the card. You need to get at the [AutoImporter preferences](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091118164210727) to do this.

Now, when you insert a card with images, they're automatically copied to the desired folder and removed from the card. No user intervention required - and when Autoimporter deletes the originals from the card they are really gone. They're not in Lightroom yet, but that's easy.

Eject the card. Now use Lightroom's importer to move or add the images to the catalog, doing all the clever things that it can do along the way.

Note:  I have tested this but don't use this approach for real. I live on the 'bootcamp' side of my Mac, so have the similar problems.

Comment: Thanks, Roddy, but a) I don't want yet another copy of my photos to manage and b) I don't always import photos from my SD card into Lightroom. I do so only for photos taken on my NEX, not my point-and-shoot.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi - Understood about the P+S vs. NEX : I can't see a way around that unless the auto-importer can somehow only recognize the NEX cards. You might like to have a look at Adobe's standalone DNG converter, as that can integrate with the image Capture app. Still not sure if original RAWs get deleted that way, though...

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, Roddy, but I think this is all too complex :) It's simpler for me to import the photos into Lightroom using Copy as DNG, and then manually delete the photos from the SD card.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi Yeah, I agree. For DNG conversion this is getting too messy. I wouldn't want RAW originals deleted until I'd verified that the DNGs were good, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Since the beginning of using Lightroom (version 3) I use the following procedure:

When I am making a memory card copy to the computer I tend to do it in four steps like this:

- Copy all files from the SD/CF card to a specific folder for all imports
- Put back the SD/CF card into the camera / unplug the camera (if using USB cable)
- Backup all imported files to an external HardDisk or a NAS
- Format the card from the camera

Lightroom can remember which files was already transferred between two transfers, but with my procedure I am sure all my pictures are properly backuped, not transferred twice in different folders and I can start a new session with an empty memory card from the camera.

I always formatted the card from the camera and I never had any issue with corrupted file system.

I know it is not the perfect solution for everyone but it works well for me.

Comment: No, Lightroom won't 'move' files from SD cards - Only copy.

Comment: But on the top option from the import menu there are "Copy as DNG, Copy, Move, Add" I expect the move to delete from the source (camera plugged or SD card)

Comment: Yes, the option's there = but for import from SD cards or cameras it's disabled. Try it and see.

Comment: I never tried, and I said probably like others said. I am always doing the above procedure, copying not moving, and the formatting (of CF/SD) from the camera to be sure the file system is not corrupted or different from a computer to the camera.

Comment: @Roddy, you are right, probably that's why it droves me to this procedure I am using now.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I need them converted to DNG during the import. Ideally, there'd be a Move as DNG import option, but there isn't.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi My procedure will work as well if you just copy as DNG instead just copy (raw). After you backup your DNG files in external disk or NAS, and format the card again from the camera.

Comment: In fact I mixed the feature to remove the originals with the Nikon Transfer program which was not able to delete protected pictures from camera. I updated my answer.

Comment: Right, but IMO dealing with yet another copy of the files in a folder is not worth it. YMMV.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi I make the backup is a separate windows (file explorer) and Lightroom is not aware of the copie. I take as well the sidecar files when I developped the raw's but always as a separate process. For Lightroom there is only one copy of the file (with or without sidecar files)

Comment: I know, but I meant to say that I don't want to have another copy of the photos on my hard disc.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi If you just import the picture you have only one instance (e.g on your mac harddisk), nobody force you to make a backup on external disk even it is strongly recommended.

Comment: Ah okay, I leave the storage to Lightroom. I have a directory that I use for all my photos in LR, but I leave it to LR to manage that directory. I don't manually move or copy files to this directory. I leave it to LR's Import dialog to put files in this directory. That simplifies file management for me -- everything in this directory is in my LR catalog, and everything in my LR catalog is in that directory. I don't want stuff outside the directory that I link to from LR. Hope I've understood your point correctly, and I hope this is useful, ruffp.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi yes, I connect LR catalog directly to my importing folder, after I can move raws (e.g. from "to_develop", to another folder) and exported images (jpeg, tiff) inside LR.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue which I found frustrating. This is the workaround I used on a mac to make it import and delete the images on the card on insert. Once you set it up it's extremely convenient. 
https://youtu.be/LhMRgEUeICY

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge, there is no way to have Lightroom delete anything off of a memory card after the fact. If you imported and used copy rather than move, then you are on the hook yourself to delete the images off your memory card.

This can also be delt with via a little bit of workflow management. Lightroom's import tool is fairly robust and full of features. You have the option making a backup copy of your imported photos as part of the import process, by specifying a secondary directory. You could set this to a folder on an external drive, for example, and always have a safe backup of your work. Personally, I try to always make it a rule to import everything off of my memory cards when I first import them. I often make multiple passes, importing chunks of similar photos with pre-assigned tags, appropriate name sequences, and possibly  applying some user edit profiles. I may have anywhere from one to ten different batches of photos to import off of a 16Gb or 32Gb CF card. Once I have imported everything, I pop it into my camera, and delete the whole card from there, while I start working on the next.

I would also note that I personally believe regularly formatting SD or CF cards is a potential source of premature writelock. Memory card data cells only have a limited number of writes, after which the card effectively becomes read only. Formatting has the tendency to touch every data cell, so I only ever delete. I've filled and deleted my CF cards many dozens of times each, and never had any issues or performance drop, where as in the same time frame, most of the local photographers I know who always do a full format have had to replace a few SD or CF cards due to failures. I recommend you format infrequently, and choose to delete instead, in order to preserve the longevity of your memory cards (given that you noted a concern about data corruption.)

Comment: Thanks, jrista. I don't format my cards at all, because a) I have never felt a need to, and b) leaving the filesystem in place means that I have a greater chance of recovering deleted files (not files moved to the /Trashes directory, but actually deleted). Besides, I thought formatting writes to only a small fraction of the storage device. It doesn't zero out every block on the device.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the DNG stuff.

Comment: Depends on what kind of format it is. A full, or low-level format erases everything on the card completely. Some cameras only support a "quick format", which deletes all the file system header, structure and directory information. Doesn't really matter if you are deleting everything on the card or just the filesystem info. Deleting the file system info still results in the same general blocks of information being touched over and over again, as the file system info is usually stored in well-known data cells. Corrupting that is no better than corrupting actual data blocks.

Comment: As for DNG, if you are Copying to DNG, then your on your own. As you said, there is no Move to DNG (wouldn't really be logical). If you follow a strict workflow, such as always importing everything on your card each and every time you import, then you can always just delete everything after importing, no big deal. I would point out that doing a simple Move rather than Copy to DNG is MANY times faster. Moving data uses low level file system operations, where as Copy to DNG has to open and read into each RAW, create a DNG and copy data in an explicit manner.

Comment: You can always convert to DNG later, and in some ways that could be more efficient as you could import multiple memory cards worth of images then batch convert the entire import. Personally, I prefer to have my RAW in their original format as well. I tried DNG for a while...things never seemed quite the same, DNG files feel a bit slower in Lightroom than working with .CR2 files...and it just feels better to always have the true original "raw" file around. But, to each his own.

Comment: I don't think low-level format is a good idea, or needed for a long time now. Yes, creating a filesystem touches only a fixed set of blocks, but these are remapped by the controller. If you write block 0 ten times, it ends up at different physical blocks, for exactly this reason -- flash has limited write cycles. When I said that I don't like formatting cards because leaving the filesystem intact gives me a higher chance of recovering files, I assume that's orthogonal to the longevity issue.

Comment: When you said that move to DNG is illogical, think of it as copy, convert to DNG, and delete the originals. That makes perfect sense. What format we want our files in after they have been copied has nothing to do with whether the originals should be deleted. I agree with you that to each his own. Since I find Copy as DNG more convenient, I'll delete the files from the SD card myself. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't really a move, though. It is a conversion and deletion of a non-similar original. The term "move" doesn't apply there, hence the "illogical".

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not too fussed about what one calls it, as long as it does what I need :) Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The memory controller on the card handles load balancing, but what handles load balancing of the memory used by the memory controller?

Comment: Just an anecdotal observation. I format my cards in-camera each time I use them after having transferred the photos on them to my computer. I have yet to experience my first issue with corruption of any CF card. I use SanDisk and Transcend brands in my Canon cameras. Some of my cards are used rather heavily and the ones I use most frequently now were purchased about two years ago.

Comment: @jrista, Lightroom 5 (and previous version too, I think) will NOT "move" images it imports from Sd cards. The "Move" option is greyed out. Only Copy/Copy as DNG are available. This is really irritating 'feature' IMO.

Comment: @Roddy, I confirm the limitation was here in LR 4 as well.

Comment: Michael, regarding your question about load-balancing, we can leave it to the card. My point is that that formatting a card is not an operation we should worry will hurt the longevity of the card, any more than creating or deleting a folder will.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you sure you haven't flipped the lock switch on your SD cards? That would render them read-only, thereby disabling move as an option. Not sure if that is the cause of the issue or not, but move should be available...at least, it seems to work with CF cards.

Comment: "Move" is not available for me when importing from SD card (unlocked), USB flash drive, or iPhone 5. Using Lr 5.3, Windows 7.

Comment: @jrista possibly a format writes *less* than deleting all the files.  It just writes the root directory sector and the FAT, once.  Deleting may update and flush multiple times, and updates subdirectorys rather than just abandoning them.